# Are client-side calls to ajax-enabled web service in ASP.Net immune to app pool recycling

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-services

**Question:** In code below, will the web service call to 'PerformLongOps' method be registered with ASP.Net so when AppDomain is unloading the web service call will not be stopped abruptly by IIS but go to completion?

PerformLongOps method can take 5 to 10 minutes to execute. I have the execution timeout set to 3600 seconds in web config.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    // This function calls the Web Service method 'PerformLongOps'.  
    function ExecuteLongOps()
    {
        Samples.MyService.PerformLongOps(OnSucceeded);
    }

    // This is the callback function that 
    // processes the Web Service return value.
    function OnSucceeded(result)
    {
        var RsltElem = document.getElementById("Results");
        RsltElem.innerHTML = result;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: It's not "fire-and-forget" when you don't forget about it

Comment: I understand that its not truly fire and forget due to the OnSucceeded event. But my question was more on the app pool recycling. I have added to my post after your comment. Thanks.